# How can I ensure closed dialogs are unregistered from INPC events?

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, dependency-properties, hashcode, dialogresult

I have an MVVM-Light based WPF application, with a dialog service (called `WindowManager`) that opens up dialog windows bound to pre-initiated dialog view-models, like this:

```
private enum ViewModelKind
{
    PlanningGridVM,
    InputDialogVM,
    TreeViewDialogVM,
    SaveFileDialogVM,
    MessageBoxVM
}

/// <summary>
/// Shows the Window linked to this ViewModel as a dialog window.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TViewModel">The type of the view model.</typeparam>
/// <returns>Tri-state boolean dialog response.</returns>
public bool? ShowDialog<TViewModel>(string key = null)
{
    ViewModelKind name;

    // Attempt to parse the type-parameter to enum
    Enum.TryParse(typeof(TViewModel).Name, out name);

    Window view = null;
    switch (name)
    {
        // removed some irrelevant cases...
        case ViewModelKind.InputDialogVM:
            view = new InputDialogView();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
                view.GetHashCode(), "New Window HashCode");
            view.Height = 200;
            result = view.ShowDialog();

        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

The dialog's XAML starts with this:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:MyCompany.Common.Behaviours"

    x:Class="MyCompany.Common.Views.InputDialogView" mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding InputDialogVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Title="{Binding DisplayName}" MinHeight="200" MinWidth="300" MaxHeight="200"
    b:WindowBehaviours.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow" ShowInTaskbar="False"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    Height="200" Width="300">
```

The view-models appropriately register with Messenger in their constructors, and they respond to initialization messages by resetting the view-model properties. This all works as intended.

In order to properly close my "Okay/Cancel" dialogs, I have an attached property called `DialogResult`, which also works as expected...

```
/// <summary>
/// DialogResult
/// </summary>
public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogResultProperty = DependencyProperty
    .RegisterAttached(
        "DialogResult",
        typeof(bool?),
        typeof(WindowBehaviours),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, DialogResultChanged));

public static void SetDialogResult(Window target, bool? value)
{
    target.SetValue(DialogResultProperty, value);
}

private static void DialogResultChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = obj as Window;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(
        window.GetHashCode(), "Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode");

    if (window != null && window.IsActive)
    {
        window.DialogResult = e.NewValue as bool?;
    }
}
```

...but for one caveat. *Did you notice that Debug output I added to track the window instance's HashCode?* It confirmed the following for me:

**When you have one reusable view-model instance, accessed by the dialog view through a DataContext binding in the XAML, and you sequentially open up a new dialog several times, those dialog instances *remain open*, even after their OnClosed event has been raised, and even though the dialog is not visible anymore!**

The nett effect of this is that I have to check the window's `IsActive` property in conjunction with checking the window for null. If I don't, the system will try to set `window.DialogResult` on every dialog phantom that still remains, resulting in a `System.InvalidOperationException` exception: "DialogResult can be set only after Window is created and shown as dialog".

---

**Debug Output**

```
New Window HashCode: 4378943
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 4378943

New Window HashCode: 53142588
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 53142588

New Window HashCode: 47653507
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 53142588
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 47653507

New Window HashCode: 57770831
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 53142588
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 57770831

New Window HashCode: 49455573
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 53142588
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 57770831
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 49455573

New Window HashCode: 20133242
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 53142588
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 57770831
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 49455573
Attempting to update DialogResult on Hashcode: 20133242
```

---

**Question**

Many times, I have seen it said that an attached behaviour stores the value of the property specific to an instance. <del>Why is this behaving the opposite way?</del>

It is clear now that those expired dialogs are still registered to the single view-model instance's INPC events. How can I ensure closed dialogs are unregistered from INPC events?

Comment: You didn't include how the DialogResultProperty is set or bound to your view model. If many windows are bound to the same view model then if the view model changes all those windows will be affected. So it is possible that DialogResultChanged is called many times for the same window because that window is bound to a property on a view model that is changed by another window

Comment: It's in the XAML code sample... b:WindowBehaviours.DialogResult="{Binding DialogResult}"

Comment: Then in the view-model, it's just a typical INPC property that raises the INPC event for property name, "DialogResult". The "Okay" and "Close" buttons just have Commands that update this property in the view-model.

Comment: @Kess - Yes, the debug output confirms this is what happened here. I just wish there was a way to remove or unregister the dialogs that have closed already... `GC.Collect()` does not work, because they are not `IDisposable`... any advice?

Comment: @Helic - Any reason you are sharing view model instances? I think it is better to use different view model instances per window. If there is some data to be shared between the view model, you can just move that data into another shared model.

Comment: Are you suggesting I stop using mvvm-light's ViewModelLocator? That would be an unacceptable solution, I'm afraid...

Comment: I'm going to try some of Mr Bugnion's suggestions in question at the link that follows. Thanks for the hints! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830517/how-to-have-multiple-pairs-view-viewmodel/2848084#2848084

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kess for pointing me in the right direction... the problem was never about destroying a dialog instance, but rather to *make sure you have a unique view-model instance for each dialog instance*! Then you only have to unregister the view-model from Messenger with the built-in `Cleanup()` method.

The trick is to use method, `GetInstance<T>(string key)` of `ServiceLocator` and to pass that key into your `WindowManager`.

---

## Solution

**InputDialogView XAML:**

*Remove the line that assigns DataContext to a ViewModelLocator property*

<del>`DataContext="{Binding InputDialogVM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`</del>

**WindowManager:**

*Use the string key passed into ShowDialog and use ServiceLocator (with the key) to fetch the unique view-model, and explicitly set view.DataContext*

```
public bool? ShowDialog<TViewModel>(string key = null)
{
    ViewModelKind name;

    Enum.TryParse(typeof(TViewModel).Name, out name);

    Window view = null;
    switch (name)
    {
        case ViewModelKind.InputDialogVM:
            view = new InputDialogView();

            // Added this line
            view.DataContext = ServiceLocator.Current
                .GetInstance<InputDialogVM>(key);

            view.Height = 200;
            result = view.ShowDialog();

        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel:**

*Create a new view-model with `ServiceLocator` using a unique string key*

```
internal void ExecuteChangeState()
{
    string key = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    InputDialogVM viewModel = ServiceLocator.Current
        .GetInstance<InputDialogVM>(key);

    // Use a nested tuple class here to send initialization parameters
    var inputDialogParams = new InputDialogVM.InitParams(
        "Please provide a reason", "Deactivation Prompt", true);

    // This message sends some critical values to all registered VM instances
    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<InputDialogVM.InitParams>(
        inputDialogParams, CommonMsg.InitInputDialog));

    if (_windowManager.ShowDialog<InputDialogVM>(key) == true)
    {
        var logEntry = new DealsLogEntry()
        {
            LogDateTime = DateTime.Now,
            LogUsername = this.CurrentUser.Username,
            Reason = viewModel.InputString
        };

        _logRepository.Create(logEntry);
    }

    // Unregister this instance from the Messenger class
    viewModel.Cleanup();
}
```